# How to Implement a timer in Metro Style App

Tags: timer, windows-runtime

I am developing a game in which I have to implement timer for showing the time that has elapsed. How can I do that?

Comment: Which language are you using? What exactly do you want to display? What have you tried? Are you asking about how to display a timer or how to get events in some time intervals where you would like to update your timer? The question seems to broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async/await way:

```
private bool isTimerRunning;

private async void StartTimer()
{
    this.isTimerRunning = true;

    while (this.isTimerRunning)
    {
        OnOneSecondPassed();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}

private void StopTimer()
{
    this.isTimerRunning = false;
}

protected virtual void OnOneSecondPassed()
{
}
```

Comment: You should (almost) never use async void. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2013/02/18/talk-the-new-async-design-patterns.aspx

Comment: I agree. What would wait for an async Task if it was the method's signature here though?

Answer (score 12):

Did you try to use `DispatcherTimer` in namespace `Windows.UI.Xaml`?

If this Timer doesn't fit to your needs, please describe why and what your requirements are.