# Countdown timer for metro App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012, countdowntimer, winrt-xaml

I'm beginner in Metro Style Developing,
I tried to make a small game that's need a timer, countdown from 10 to 0.
But at this Visual Studio there is no Timer Component, and DispatcherTimer Not mapped to an xmlns.

I Tried to use TimeSpan, that have this field "TicksPerSecond" But this example dosen't help me to make my countdown timer :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tickspersecond.aspx

TimeSpan also have this method "FromSeconds", and i Can't also use this one for my countdown timer : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds.aspx

also I Read this question at stackoverflow :
[How to Implement a timer in Metro Style App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410072/how-to-implement-a-timer-in-metro-app)
but this isn't useful.

what can I do for this countdown timer?

Comment: How can the answers to that question not be helpful?  Use the DispatcherTimer class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There is a [CountdownControl](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/13069#228449) in the [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://bit.ly/WinRTXamlToolkit) that could help you too - it is basically using an animation that takes 1s between events. Another option would be to use the async/await keywords - you can basically say await Task.Delay(1000) to wait for a second and call it in a loop to count down seconds. This would also be portable.

Comment: Thank you Filip, 
I don't Used WinRT before this, I download the sources , but I can't find any dll files to add to my project reference. I'm not familiar with this.
and then, I tried to use Task.Delay(1000), I define this function: Public async Task dellay()
{
await task.Delay(1000)
}
and Call this function, But it wasn't any effect on my App, also I tried to use only this " Task.Delay(1000) " and it has same result like the my "dellay" function

Comment: Use NuGet to add the reference to your WinRT project.

Comment: Sure. Do you have a link to how to do that for WinRT or is it the same as for say Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by xmlns, do you want to use [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx) in XAML? Ok, it is not possible, but it is not a big deal, just use it from your code.

In my application, I'm intensively using [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609). The Rx v2.0 Beta supports winrt, so the timer issue could be solved in the following way (again in the code behind, not in the XAML):

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Take(10).ForEachAsync(x =>
{
    Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => 
    {
        new MessageDialog("seconds: " + (10-x), "timer").ShowAsync();
    });
});
```

The big plus of this approach - your code will more portable between frameworks. Hope this helps.