# Visual C# Countdown Timer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, timer, project-setup

### Overview

I am trying to create a countdown test application. The problem is, none of the classes which are normally used to do this are available to me. I know this has a lot to do with the fact that I am coding for windows RT using windows 8.

### Full Setup:

Language: Visual C#
IDE: Visual Studio 2012
OS: Windows 8
Output Type: Windows Store App
Target Framework: Not Selectable
Project Type (Selected Via New Project): Unknown

### I cannot access the following:

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatchTimer
System.Windows.Forms.Timer
System.Timers.Timer
System.Threading.Thread
//The Timer Object (Should be in the toolbox in the design form)
```

### Additional

I would like to get a sample timer application working. This way, I can integrate the needed functionality into my main project.

We are using .Net 4.5, while many of these problems are fixed in .Net 4.5.1, but we need to write our application to target the lower level framework.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Improve your google skills! :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455275/countdown-timer-for-metro-app

Answer (score 0):

Is System.DateTime available to you? That's the only other option that comes to mind, although I haven't ever coded for RT.

Comment: Yes it is, but what did you have in mind? I am guessing something along the lines of creating my own helper class / utility to do what I need.